# Error running application that depends on WMI

Tags: .net, deployment, wmi

i have just developed an app that uses system.manament class, but my friend is having problem using the app as it gives errors. He has winxp sp3 and .Net framework 2.0 installed, just as i have.

> ```
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> ```
>
> 'System.Management.MTAHelper' threw an exception. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154.
>          at System.Management.MTAHelper..cctor()

how can i deploy this application making sure wmi is present?
what could be the problem?

Comment: please note that i referenced `system.management.dll` and imported `system.management` in my application. do i have to deploy and register this dll with my application?

Comment: You cannot deploy and register these DLLs. They're part of the .NET framework, and therefore you have to install the proper version of the framework in it's entirety. (They probably depend on other DLLs that would not match either, and so on and so forth.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that WMI is running. In command line:

```
net start winmgmt
```

If you distribute your app as windows service you can put a [dependency on WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.dependentservices.aspx) during service installation. It is also worth looking at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/10/20/get-wmiobject-the-type-initializer-for-system-management-mtahelper-threw-an-exception.aspx):

> So I went to
>   HKCR\CLSID{A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884}\InprocServer32(Default)
>   in my x64 environment, and saw the following path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll.
>
> Customer changed the C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll path he found in
>   there to the right one, and he didn't get the error again.

If you serch registry as Ken White [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457144/error-running-application-that-depends-on-wmi/7457185#7457185) and it does not have 'HKCR\CLSID{A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884}' it might be worth reinstalling .NET. Also look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926640).

Comment: This is wrong. The `HRESULT` shown is `class not registered`. A service not running will not cause it. Search google for `HRESULT 0x80040154' for several discussions.

Comment: @ken please check my comment.

Comment: regarding deployment, you should not distribute any additional dlls. System.management is part of .NET and you already depend on .NET. Try reinstalling .NET if you could not find A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884 in registry.

Answer (score 2):

The `0x80040154` `HRESULT` error given in the message means that the COM class used is not registered on the system. (It can also mean that a dependent class isn't registered; your COM class can't resolve the dependency and this error code is returned causing the exception to be raised.)

There are obviously differences between the operating systems or frameworks installed on your machine and your friend's. We can't tell you what they might be, because you didn't post any code. You can probably start tracking it down by searching the Windows registry on your machine for the `CLSID` shown in the error message (`{A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884}`).

Comment: +1 For pointing out that not running WMI service can not be the cause of the issue.